# How to pass a value from default.php to view.html.php through ajax - joomla3.x

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to pass a value to view.html.php from default.php.

This is in Joomla 3.x

- folder/tmpl/default.php
- folder/view.html.php

**default.php**

```
<input placeholder="Enter a value" type="text" id="field-5" >

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#field-5").keyup(function (e) { 
      var exam = $(this).val(); 
      $.post('http://localhost/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/view.html.php', {'value':exam});  
   });
});
</script>
```

**view.html.php**

```
$value = $_REQUEST['value'];
echo $value;
```

i need that $value for filtering a data table, i dont know if this is working or this the right code, or its just i need to refresh my data table and i dont know how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work this way. Your URL in the ajax call must be something like the following:

```
JURI::root().'index.php?option=com_your_extension&view=view_name'
```